# Debugging in NetBeans without changing focus

Tags: java, netbeans, debugging

I have a program which uses the Robot class in Java to automate a bunch of keypresses and clicks. The problem I am encountering is not being able to set breakpoints on certain methods to debug because the focus would change when I skip to the next expression.

Is there a way I can bypass this by changing the default continue hotkey (F8) in NetBeans to a low-level keyboard hook that will check system wide?

The reason for this is because the macro I am designing runs too fast for me to see each action occurring. If I set breakpoints along the program, I must alt-tab to the IDE and continue to the next breakpoint, which, unfortunately, interferes with the macro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to interact with the system in a way that interferes with your program, you must separate your debugger from your program.

In other words, run the two on separate machines and do a remote debug from one machine to another.

The easiest way to do so if you don't *have* or want to use two machines, is to run your program in a virtual machine.  A cheap solution is to use vmware player along with a Linux distribution supported by Netbeans.

Comment: It doesn't actually interfere with the system. The problem is that i have to alt-tab to Netbeans in order to go to the next breakpoint. This interferes with the macro.

Comment: So your debugging  _ does_ affect your program.

Comment: Yes, it does. Would it be possible to slow down the execution of a program in Netbeans? Having the ability to do so would be useful as it would allow me to analyze each action very much like setting breakpoints.

Comment: This would most likely be a good candidate for an aspectJ-program where you tell it to match every source line and insert a suitable Thread.sleep().  I do not believe there is a debugger at the moment that can do this automatically.

Comment: @Thobjorn Oh ok. Well, it will be tedious. Only a few hundred lines of code to go through. I'm sure i can create a macro for it. TY for your input.

Comment: Consider just doing it in AspectJ then.